# Motherboard has 2 usb 3.0 connectors but no header for me to connect on the actual board

Tags: motherboard

in the manual it says you use the computer to use usb 3.0 what does this mean?

m5a97 le r2.0 motherboard

also can corsair vengeance lp 8 gb black version be compatible with it

Answer (score 2):

From Asus's home page and the manual , both rear USB ports are USB 3.0, and you have one header which I have circled for 2 more USB 3.0 ports (for things like USB 3.0 front panel headers).

[image]

You can find a list of supported ram [here](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/M5A97_R20/#support) (In future, one question a question please! And note that all the information you needed *is* available quite readily on the asus home page.

Comment: i dont think i saw that but ill go look

Comment: on my model it doesnt have the usb 3.0 header both models le r2.0 and r2.0 it says due to usb 3.0 controller limitation, usb devices can only be used under windows os environment and after the usb 3.0 driver installations

Comment: so does this mean i cant use the usb 3.0 on the front of the case? or would a converter work?

Comment: Practically, not easily. I suppose you might be able to do something clever with the right converter/converters.